# How to place three div tags one below another?

Tags: jquery, html, css

**Consider the following code..**

```
<div class="button_con" style="width: 400px; height: 500px; text-align: center;"> 
<div id="canvas1" title="Buffer Indicator">Buffer Count :   ${buffer1}</div>
<div id="canvas2" title="CPU Indicator">Cpu Usage :     ${cpu1}%</div>
<div id="canvas3" title="Memory Indicator">Memory Usage:    ${memory1}%</div>

</div>
```

**This is my CSS.**

```
#canvas1 {
display: inline;   
font:italic bold 14px/34px Georgia, serif;
text-align: center;
line-height: 8;
text-transform:uppercase;
height: auto;
width: auto;

}

#canvas2 {
display: inline;   
font:italic bold 14px/34px Georgia, serif;
text-align: center;
line-height: 8;
text-transform:uppercase;
height: auto;
width: auto;

}

#canvas3 {
display: inline;   

font:italic bold 14px/34px Georgia, serif;
text-align: center;
line-height: 8;
text-transform:uppercase;
height: auto;
width: auto;

}
```

The div tags here are displaying next to each other.The div tag contains jsDraw2dx api elements, but I don't think that should affect the div tag's position. How do I manage it to display one below another?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing:

```
display: inline;
```

by:

```
display: block;
```

Comment: I inserted `display: block;` but I need to display line to be on the left side of the div tag, not on bottom . Is this possible?

Comment: I don't think I've understand what you want...   You want a `border-line`?

Comment: @lifeatstake you are telling abt which line here

Comment: The code which you suggested yielded this result [link](http://snag.gy/BjXut.jpg), but I want this [link](http://snag.gy/fhUBL.jpg)

Comment: Ok. And how want you them to be? (an image would be appreciated)

Comment: I dont get what you need share some screen shots to represent it.

Comment: I have shared some links. Please have a look.

Comment: Yes, we've seen the result, but can you reproduce the expected result. (e.g with Paint)

Comment: can you please add reason behind the replacement of code or add what does `display: inline;` and `display: block;` exactly?

Comment: @Xlander I need to display it in html. Where does paint comes in picture?

Comment: `display: inline;` will make the element take the width of what is inside(unless specified) and make other element (sibling) stick to each other. Whereas `display: block;` will make the element take the width, i.e 100% of its parent (unless specified).

Comment: @lifeatstake I was asking for an illustration of your expected result.

Comment: @Xlander It's okay. I got it. I changed the x,y coordinates of the circle which is drawn.

Answer (score 1):

The reason that the divs are appearing next to each other is because you're setting their display property to 'inline'.

By default, divs have a display property of 'block', which is the behaviour that you want. You can either change the code to read:

```
display: block;
```

Or simply, remove the declaration completely and the default behaviour will kick in.

On a side note, your situation would be better suited to use classes instead of ids since the styling is identical for all three divs. See how this would work here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gEyDo